# Building Mobile applications( IOS & Android) using Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

We are building a mobile application that needs to work on both Android and Iphone. To save time and development effort, we are thinking of using Adobe Flash Builder 4.5, instead of Eclipse (for Android) and XCode.

Is it safe to ditch eclipse and XCode and stick to Flash Builder, what kind of problems I am expected to face?

We are already having trouble using the TextInput for Right To Left languages, both in android and IOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems you faced are common, but you made the correct choice.

I use Flash builder 4.5 for both those platforms, and Windows + Linux (only up to air 2.6)

Flash builder combined with Web services is a very powerful development solution.

**The worst trouble you will face, is getting the solution to the App Stores. Now there is a journey of its own!**

Hope this build your confidence.

Comment: if you get stuck, let me know.